# CGPoint to CLLLocationCoordinate2D - convertPoint toCoordinateFromView not working

Tags: objective-c

I've got a mapping project I wrote a few months back where I use a helper class which passes in touch parameters to my main mapview class. Using the following method I can normally convert the CGPoint x and y information over to a geographic coordinate:

```
- (void)moveDetect:(NSSet *)touches :(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
NSLog(@"X:%f  Y:%f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);

CLLocationCoordinate2D touchCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

float lat = touchCoordinate.latitude;
float lng = touchCoordinate.longitude;
NSLog(@"Touch Coordinate: %f %f", lat, lng);}
```

I've recently tried to reuse the code in a different project, but the conversion does not occur. Halting and stepping into the touchCoordinate variable shows values initially (latitude = {CLLocationDegrees}3.23141e-306 and longitude={CLLocationDegrees}5.46786e-48), but once you reach the next line of code the values are both 0. I've reviewed both projects, but have been unable to figure out why one works while the other does not. I appreciate the time, and look forward to any suggestions that could lead me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
  - (void)moveDetect:(NSSet *)touches :(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.mapView]; //here locationInView it would be mapView
    NSLog(@"X:%f  Y:%f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
 }
```

Comment: After messing around for another four hours I finally started over with a new project, except this time I created it solely for iPad. Tested the code and works fine, so apparently something in the project was corrupted. In the old project I removed the universal project settings, and set it up for iPad only as a test, but it behaved exactly the same. Since I cannot narrow down the exact cause I will leave this unanswered for now.

Comment: As a side note I also created the original project from AppCode rather than Xcode which could be to blame. The working project was created in Xcode, and works like a charm.